# Separate log text according to paragraph?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

```
****************
* 192.168.1.1
****************
ssh -q 192.168.1.1 ntpstat
synchronised to NTP server (192.168.204.1) at stratum 5
time correct to within 281 ms
polling server every 1024 s

****************
* 192.168.1.3
****************
ssh -q 192.168.1.3 ntpstat
synchronised to NTP server (192.168.1.2) at stratum 12
time correct to within 57 ms
polling server every 1024 s
```

I have this log text and I want to separate it like :

paragraph :

```
****************
* 192.168.1.1
****************
ssh -q 192.168.1.1 ntpstat
synchronised to NTP server (192.168.204.1) at stratum 5
time correct to within 281 ms
polling server every 1024 s
```

paragraph 2:

```
****************
* 192.168.1.3
****************
ssh -q 192.168.1.3 ntpstat
synchronised to NTP server (192.168.1.2) at stratum 12
time correct to within 57 ms
polling server every 1024 s
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Separate into what? different files?

Answer (score 2):

If your input file is `test.log` and you want to split it on each empty line, creating a bunch of numbered `test-XXX.log` files, you could do it with a Bash loop like this:

```bsh
number=1
while read line ; do 
    echo "$line" >> "test-$number.log"
    if [[ -z "$line" ]] ; then 
        ((number++))
    fi
done < test.log
```

or shortened and in one line:

```bsh
n=1;while read l;do echo "$l">>"test-$n.log";if [[ -z "$l" ]];then ((n++));fi;done<test.log
```

This reads the input file line by line and increases a counter every time it encounters an empty line in the input. The output file name to which each line gets appended contains the counter, so that the data ends up in different files.

Answer (score 1):

You can split files into records, separated by one or more blank lines, using Awk in *paragraph mode* by setting an empty record separator `RS`

You can then create numerically increasing names for the pieces by appending the record number `NR` to a basename of your choice:

```
awk -vRS= '{print > "paragraph" NR}' log.txt
```

---

Another option would be to use `csplit` with a regular expression `/^$/` to match empty lines:

```
csplit -sz --prefix='paragraph' --suffix-format='%d' log.txt '/^$/' '{*}'
```

You may omit the `--prefix` and `--suffix-format` if you don't mind the default filename sequence `xx00`, `xx01` etc.